# run file in sphinx ipython directive

Tags: python, ipython, python-sphinx

I'm new to `sphinx` and struggling.

Here is my problem. I have a file `usage.py`, that I want to use in my documentation. It contains pure python code, like so (actual code much longer):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# [start1]
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5)
# [end1]

# [start2]
min(a)
# [end2]

def plot():
    plt.plot(a)
```

I'd like to be able to use this file in my `usage.rst` file like so:

```
Sample use
==========

In the first section, I just want to show some code:

.. literalinclude:: usage.py
   :language: python
   :start-after: [start1]
   :end-before: [end1]

In the second section, I want to plot something:

.. plot:: usage.py plot

   The array, graphically.

And in the third section, I want to actually show interpreter output:

.. ipython:: python

   run usage.py
   min(a)
```

**The problem is in the third section: it doesn't compile:**

```
    run usage.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...even though that line works perfectly fine when entered manually at the terminal `ipython` interface.

I hope my intent is clear: I want all my code to be in a separate `.py` file for easy maintenance, and use different parts of it in different directives.

Ideally, I can instruct `ipython` to run the whole file up to a certain line number and show what the output to the final input line is.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**EDIT: partial solution**

This did the trick and finished without errors:

```
%run 'source/usage.py'
min(a)
```

However, it won't **show the contents** of the file it's run.

Substituting `%load` for `%run` *does* show the contents, as desired, when manually using `ipython` on the terminal. But if I make the same changes to the rst directive, the code doesn't even get executed. If you have any thoughts on this, do let me know :)

Comment: A quick scan of the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sphinxext.html) makes it look like you can only use Python code, not shell commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. I mean to use the `ipyhton` "magic commands" instead of shell commands, sorry if that wasn't clear. I've edited the question for more clarity